# Forwarding calls to underlying object in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I have the following class definition:

```scala
class Foo[T](iteratorThunk: () => Iterator[T]) {
  def values = iteratorThunk()
}
```

And I would like `Foo` to have all the methods that `Iterator` exposes, while still returning objects of type `Foo`. For instance, I would like to be able to do:

```scala
val a = new Foo({ () => List(1, 2, 3).toIterator })
val b = new Foo({ () => List(4, 5, 6).toIterator })
val c = a ++ b
```

And have `c` equal to:

```scala
new Foo({ () => a.values ++ b.values })
```

I had a look at forwarders ([`IterableForwarder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/IterableForwarder.html), [`TraversableForwarder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/TraversableForwarder.html), ...), but none seemed fit to forward methods to an `Iterator`, and I would still like to keep `Foo` as both the static and dynamic result type.

What is the best way to achieve this behavior, without defining every forwarding method?

Comment: Take a look at the definition of the Iterator trait, only the hasNext and next methods are abstract, so you can easily supply them. A potentially more important point is that Iterator extends TraversableOnce and so is intended for a single pass through its values which limits the use of a proxy or derived form. Ask yourself whether it might be better to just use the iterator.

Comment: I need the `Foo` class as it is, and not only as an `Iterator` because I need to be able to do more than one pass through its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the Foo class as it is, and not only as an Iterator because I
>   need to be able to do more than one pass through its values.

Then you want either a `Traverable` or an `Iterable`. To have them work as you wish, you need to extend both them and `TraversableLike` or `IterableLike`, through which you'll specify the return type. And you'll need to provide both a `Builder` and a `CanBuildFrom` as well.

Here's a simple implementation:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.mutable.LazyBuilder
class Foo[T](iteratorThunk: () => Iterator[T]) extends Iterable[T] with IterableLike[T, Foo[T]] {
  def iterator = iteratorThunk()
  override protected def newBuilder = new Foo.FooBuilder[T]
}

object Foo {
  class FooBuilder[T] extends LazyBuilder[T, Foo[T]] {
    def result(): Foo[T] = {
      val coll = parts.toList.flatten
      new Foo(() => coll.iterator)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've complemented your implementation with a proper CanBuildFrom and got it working as I wanted.

Comment: Do you think that it's possible to avoid the `parts.toList.flatten` part, so that the iterators that are added to the builder don't get evaluated there?

Comment: @JoaoAzevedo You want `iteratorThunk` to return the same elements every time, right? Since an `Iterator` can only be traversed once, you'll have to "save" it somewhere. That's what iterator's `dup` does, for example. Given that, you might as well save it on the builder.

Comment: Yes, but the `toList` call forces the iterator elements to be evaluated. Can we be lazier and delay this evaluation?

Comment: @JoaoAzevedo Yes. Use `toStream`. Or fold the iterators with `++`, and then apply `toStream` over that. It's difficult to figure out exactly what will be done lazily, what will be forced, so one has to experiment with different ways of combining them.